# F19 in Mac keyboard

Tags: drivers, keyboard, apple

I am using an Apple Aluminium keyboard.

Keys F1..F18 work well, however, F19 is not recognized.

Actually, when checked with `xev`, it is recognized.. but I cannot assign a shortcut to F19 in gnome or any other app.

Is this a known issue? any tips on how to fix it?

**update: Output from `xev` when clicking F19**

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xd000001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0x0, time 64297953, (160,-20), root:(1351,629),
    state 0x10, keycode 197 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xd000001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0x0, time 64297960, (160,-20), root:(1351,629),
    state 0x10, keycode 197 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

**update 2: Output from `xev` when clicking F18**

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xd000001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0xd000002, time 69242803, (47,44), root:(2043,870),
    state 0x10, keycode 196 (keysym 0x1008ff49, XF86Launch9), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xd000001,
    root 0x1e6, subw 0xd000002, time 69242806, (47,44), root:(2043,870),
    state 0x10, keycode 196 (keysym 0x1008ff49, XF86Launch9), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I guess it has something to do with F18=`XF86Launch9` and F19=`NoSymbol`.. where is this mapped?

Comment: Please open a terminal and show what gives CTRL+V then F19 - (the ctrl+v before a key returns the key code, give it a try with other keys)

Comment: Nothing happens.. If I do it with F8, then I get `^[[19~`

Comment: which keycode and keysym is produced when pressing F18?

Comment: @danzel updated

Comment: I guess it has something to do with `XF86Launch9` and `NoSymbol`.. where is this mapped? Is there something like `XF86Launch10` ?

Comment: Did you choose the correct keyboard layout in system settings? For many locales, there are variants like "macintosh" or "extended". Those settings are horrible in gnome, IIRC. In KDE I can select the keyboard model separately in settings. The mappings you asked for are in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols`, but you shouldn't mess around too much in there because it is quite complicated. The mapping for F18 is in the file called `inet`. There is XF86LaunchA (to F) which you could try.

Comment: I guess the easiest solution is specifying the correct keyboard model in `/etc/default/keyboard`. The possible values for XKBMODEL can be found [here](https://github.com/csulmone/X11/blob/master/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst), your's is probably one of the `applealu_` models. Try that first because you can mess up your whole layout by manipulating the xkb configuration files.

Comment: Thanks @danzel for the tips. I managed to get it working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I could fix it.. or should I say hacked it.. not sure how clean this actually is.

In case somebody is interested:

1) Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet`. Search for:

```
    key <FK17>   {      [ XF86Launch8       ]       };
    key <FK18>   {      [ XF86Launch9       ]       };
};
```

and add one more line

```
    key <FK17>   {      [ XF86Launch8       ]       };
    key <FK18>   {      [ XF86Launch9       ]       };
    key <FK19>   {      [ XF86LaunchA       ]       };
};
```

2) run `setxkbmap -layout us` or whatever layout you are using to refresh the corresponding configuration.

After these changes, F19 is mapped to `XF86LaunchA` and can be used without issues.

**Note:** Thanks @danzel for the tips.